# How can I render faster?

Tags: rendering

I'm using a dual-core Intel i7 with 8GB RAM and Intel (R) HD graphics 520. I'm currently following and trying to make this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhjK-6t9Gqs but my issue is that baking alone took me about 2 hours and I'm worried that the animation will take days. Is there any way to render faster?

Comment: Decrease samples?

Comment: Baking the particles is typically done only once an entire animation not for every frame. Try to render a frame and see what thats get you.

Comment: [This particular guide](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/) is very helpful for cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You mean render faster not baking.Then decrease the no of samples,turn off anti aliasing and maybe even decrease the resolution of your animation.Of course these all come at the cost of quality.Give it a try and see if you're satisfied with the graphics quality you get.